# how is react faster and more efficient when it ran js code unnecessarily

Tags: reactjs

I am horrified to see my code running multiple time to render/update one UI.
I have a component that accepts a new props id to be used for API call. When a component receives props. it ran render unnecessarily, I use componentDidUpdate to call API it ran render the second time. Doesn't this make your program slower? Or am I structuring my react app incorrectly and don't understand react at all.

Also I had a setState to allow conditional rendering, so its 
render - when it receives id props
render - when I setState to loading
render - when I toggle setState to show API result

So its 3 render for 1 UI change.

Comment: Don't worry about the performance unless it becomes a problem.

Comment: If you share your code, it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Well, does it make the program slower? If you can't see any difference, it's not really a problem, is it? Also note that React doesn't update the DOM if nothing has changed even if the render method runs multiple times.

Comment: I do not know how to test whether my program is slower than it is. But it probably wont notice a big issue since the program is considered small (single page app)

Answer (score 1):

React uses Virtual DOM and a diffing algorithm to update the real DOM so the real DOM is not changed on every render. Only the parts which actually change are updated hence the performance and efficiency is one of the best.

Comment: Is there a way to see the Virtual DOM not Updating the DOM on a particular render?

Answer (score 0):

React uses virtual DOM to modify the DOM element and does dirty checking of its virtual DOM objects to actual DOM objects. If your render method is calling multiple times, you need to check how well you are using state and props and life cycle components.

Comment: how do I know if the virtual DOM is not updating the DOM on every render?

Comment: In developer mode of your browser you can see. The modified one's will be highlighted. Please refer https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html and go to developer tools section for more info.